# Azurerm "Root Tenant Group" unauthorized

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

We have a Azure Subscription which is created in default management group (Root Tenant Group). I am trying to read the information of this subscrption and managment group using
"data "azurerm_management_group" "xx"
""
But i am getting an unautorized error
reading Management Group (Display Name "Tenant Root Group"): listing Management Groups: managementgroups.Client#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed"
""

I have a Security Reader access on the managment group and only owner is above me.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this?

PS: For a module dependency limitation i using an older version of azurerm which is v2.95.0.

expecting a managment group id to be read using terraform code

Comment: How is the AzureRM provider authenticating with Azure?  If you're using a service principal then what role assignments does that service principal have over the management group?

Comment: I am doing wo things for that
az login 
After that there is a script i run to export ARM_ACCESS_KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Expecting a managment group id to be read using terraform code.

To retrieve information about the `Parent Management Group` using Terraform, the `Global Administrator` role is required, not the `Security Reader role`. The `Security Reader` role is intended for accessing information about `Child Groups`, not `Parent Group` information. Refer to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin#how-does-elevated-access-work) for more details

> Note: If you are a [Global Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#global-administrator) in Azure AD, you can assign yourself access to all Azure subscriptions and management groups in your directory.

[image]

**Terraform code:**

```
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "=2.95.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
      skip_provider_registration ="true"
    }
    data "azurerm_management_group" "example" {
      display_name = "Tenant Root Group"
    }
    output "display_name" {
      value = data.azurerm_management_group.example.display_name
    }
```

**Terraform Apply**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i thought the display name should be either Tenant Root Group or i can use name which is the UUID of the tenant in format ("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"), this is the example ofcourse. 
So i was thinking did i hit an exception that the default managment group (Tenant Root Group)  cannot be read by anyone except a owner. See the structure of my environment below:

Comment: Moreover when i have the sufficent right as security reader in the tenat root group, i do not see what extra changes you have made to make it work.

Comment: **Management Group** and **Parent Management Group** is different, if you want check Parent Management Group ,Here is the  attribute to check parent_management_group_id - The ID of any Parent Management Group. For more details check [Here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/management_group.html#attributes-reference)

Comment: I have added my scenario here, there is no parent managment group or hierachy. It's just a default mgmt grp and a subscription under that.

Comment: Now we are talking :). Sorry unable to upvote your answer due to my account limitation (less reputation)  but thanks for your help